# Need help with regex to parse expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have an expression:

```
((((the&if)|sky)|where)&(end|finish))
```

What I need is to put a space between symbols and words so that it ends up like:

```
( ( ( ( the & if ) | sky ) | where ) & ( end | finish ) )
```

The regex I came up with is `(\w)*[(\&*)(\|*)]` which only gets me:

`( ( ( ( the& if) | sky) | where) & ( end| finish) )`

Could I get a little help here from a resident regex guru please?  I will be using this in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Since you're using C#, try this:

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, @"([^\w\s]|\w(?!\w))(?!$)", "$1 ");
```

That inserts a space after any character that matches the following conditions:

- Is neither a letter, number, underscore, or whitespace

  - OR is a word character that is NOT followed by another word character
- AND is not at the end of a line.

Answer (score 2):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b|(?<=\W)(?=\W)", " ");
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b      # Match a position at the start or end of a word
|       # or...
(?<=\W) # a position between two
(?=\W)  # non-word characters
```

(and replace those with a space).

Comment: I've found this site helpful in developing and testing regex patterns:  http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Comment: This will lead to something like `hello world` being converted to `hello   world` (3 spaces). I'm not sure if that's an issue here, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a space after each word and after each non-word character (so look for `\W|\w+` and replace it with the match and a space. e.g. in Vim:

```
:s/\W\|\w\+/\0 /g
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
(\w+|&|\(|\)|\|)(?!$)
```

which means a word, or a `&` symbol, or a `(` symbol, or a `)` symbol, or a `|` symbol not followed by an end of string; and then replace a match with a match + space symbol. By using c# this could be done like:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(
                 @"((((the&if)|sky)|where)&(end|finish))", 
                 @"(\w+|&|\(|\)|\|)(?!$)", 
                 "$+ "
             );
```

Now `result` variable contains a value:

```
( ( ( ( the & if ) | sky ) | where ) & ( end | finish ) )
```